# Openerp sxw report

Tags: odoo, reportlab

I've made some changes to `addons/sale/report/sale_order.rml`, but OpenERP continues to display the old version of the report. How can I make it use the new version of the RML file?

I think it might be loading the report definition from the binary data in `ir_act_report_xml.report_rml_content_data` instead of loading the RML file.

Comment: can you give some more information? what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I've edited your question to try and make it clearer. Did I get it right? Have you checked that the `report_rml_content_data` field is not null?

Answer (score 0):

I searched the code for references to `report_rml_content_data` and couldn't find any that use it or populate it. Are you using any extra addons beyond the ones in the `addons/6.1` branch? All my records in that table have null in that field.

I would suggest you try setting that field to null and see if it starts reading your new file. Do it in a copy of your live database, of course.

Are you really sure that it's not using the RML file? I've had some mistakes in RML files that make it ignore a section. Try changing the title at the top of the page, or adding an "X" to the order name to see if those changes appear when you run the report.

Comment: I want openerp to run the rml file in my report folder and not the one from binary data in table ir_act_report-xml. I am unable to add serial numbers in sxw report it puts extra dot[.] if i use formatting and bullets don

Comment: OK, I think I've answered your new question, @user1540295.

Answer (score -1):

If you stop this feature the problem will raise is you can not print any of the report, cause in OpenERP Report case the `rml` is template using which report is rendered.

Still if you want todo it then check for the file :

- /server/openerp/report/report_sxw.py
- /server/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py
- /server/openerp/osv/orm.py

This file will help you to mute your requirements.
But **Be care full** it may stop your report engine.

Regards

Comment: I want openerp to run the rml file in my report folder and not from

Comment: I want openerp to take report from rml file in report folder and not from the binary data it stores in table. I am unable to add serial numbers 1,2,3 in my report it adds extra dot[.]